# Load user data after login

Tags: php, oop, authentication

For a school project, I'm programming an application of banks account management where I have a procedure like this : User attempt to login. If it's succeeds, I load all his data inside a main Client object.

This implies an hydratation cascade : While hydrating itself, a main `Client` object launch the hydratation of others object that are stored inside  objects arrays that `Client` contains. E.g. the `Client` class contains a `bankAccounts` attribute which is an array of `BankAccount` objects which contains an `operations` attribute which is an array of `Operation` objects and so on… finally, this `Client` object is stored inside `$_SESSION`.

I'm still learning OOP and that was my first attempt to structure my classes and use them. Now, I'm wondering if it's good to make the things like that ? If I compare to some other projects i've seen, they seems to request their data using SQL requests each time it's necessary. E.g. If the user visits the page displaying the bank accounts, the data will be requested to the database. So, if this user refresh it 50 times, it will repeat these requests 50 times.

What I like with my way is that once the client is connected, all informations I need are  easily accessible and organised, I no longer need to request them. On the other hand  if some data are modified, deleted, I will need to update my client object. Also its need more performance when the user login.

What's the good practices about that ? Does what I do is common ? the right thing to do ?  to avoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database Caching is the right way for fast process.

The database permits you to cache your queries as text files for reduced database load but

> Need to care for dynamic data.

1. If you are login and stored the result in a text file.
2. In between this user information modified by another panel.
3. Then you can't view dynamic data for this user.
4. You can manage this by whenever this user info update from another way then you’ll want to delete the cache files associated with this user using the unique file name.

**Database catch write function logic**

```
public function write($userid, $object)
{
        $filename = $userid;
        if ( ! is_dir($dir_path) && ! @mkdir($dir_path, 0750))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (write_file($dir_path.$filename, serialize($object)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        chmod($dir_path.$filename, 0640);
        return TRUE;
}
```

Please refer this CI DB_cache for OOP and core logic [CI DB_cache.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_cache.php)

Core logic is common so you can take understanding from here : [CI database caching guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html)